# UIPageViewController ChildViewController disappears when UIActivityViewController is being used with Mail or SMS

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm currently using a `UIPageViewController` to show `ChildViewcontrollers` and created my own pagination for this.

On the last screen of my `UIPageViewController` there is a share  button. when a user taps this and selects either `Message` or `Email` and he goes back to the app. Everything regarding the child pages disappears from the view controller.

After checking it with the interface inspector it shows that the `UIPageViewController` is completely gone after selecting one of those 2 options.

When selecting anything else like `Notepad`, `Facebook`, `Facebook Messenger`, `Twitter` etc. everything is completely fine.

In the base view I've added the `UIPageViewController` as follows

let pageViewController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, navigationOrientation: .horizontal, options: nil)

```
controller?.addChildViewController(pageViewController)

containerView.addSubview(pageViewController.view)

pageViewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
pageViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

pageViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBarBottom.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
pageViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
pageViewController.view.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
pageViewController.view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor).isActive = true

pageViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: controller)
```

when I comment out `pageViewController.view.translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` the `UIPageViewController` does display after tapping `Message or Mail` but it displays full screen which it shouldn't.

Does anyone know how I can possibly fix this?